# ChromeOS terminal keeps flashing Ubuntu on Chromebook

Tags: chromebook, crouton

I installed Ubuntu (Xubuntu) on a Chromebook laptop following these instructions http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343

It has worked perfectly and I have been running Ubuntu and ChromeOS in parallel. After the last ChromeOS update, a weird and disturbing issue has arisen. When I am in Ubuntu and perform any action (open a document, open a folder, run a program), this of course corresponds to something happening in the shell terminal, so a few lines are added in the shell console. The problem is, whenever this happens, the shell console flashes in (i.e. appears on top of Ubuntu) for the half second it takes for these lines to be written. This has never happened before.

It is difficult to find keywords to describe this problem, and I have not seen anyone posting about it online. I hope I have made myself understood. Any hint is much appreciated.

Also, as you have probably noticed, I am not at all an expert on these things, so I would need a step-by-step guiding.

Comment: Please add some screenshots.

Comment: Update: after a reboot, things are working fine. It may still be relevant to solve the problem, since it seems to indicate some instability, but for my purpose, I am satisfied.